# Do we say "Do you hear the toy saying or sounding 'I love you' "?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-request

I am playing with my son and the toy suddenly made a sound of "I love you".

How do I express in that situation?

**Do you hear the toy saying or sounding "*I love you*"**?

But only human can say, objects like a toy can't, right?

Comment: Objects can say things; my car says things; my computer does too.

Comment: There was an incident in the 1980s when speaking dolls were on sale in the US. The voice device was crude, and the words fuzzy. Due to a delivery error, a California store in a mainly Anglo area got dolls with Spanish voice chips. Instead of saying "I love Mommy" they said "Quiero Mami" and caused a scare because the kids thought the doll was saying "Kill our mommy".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/say) defines **say** as

> to **pronounce words** or sounds, to express a thought, opinion, or suggestion, or to state a fact or instruction

There is no requirement for the speaker to be human. If a device (toy, lift, ATM, etc) makes noises that are intended to sound like speech, we use the word **say**.